# Updating picture after \pause

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm trying to make a slide where I'd start showing with a picture and then adding one by one items (in a \itemize structure) and I'd like the same picture to change for another one once introduced the third item.

Is there a way to do that without making a total new slide?

Cheers.

Comment: Might be an idea if you started by posting some code. Also note that `\includegraphics` supports the `<>` notation, see the Beamer manual to see where is should be placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}% loads graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics<1>[height=0.3\paperheight]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics<2>[height=0.3\paperheight]{example-image-b}
        \includegraphics<3>[height=0.3\paperheight]{example-image-c}
    \end{center}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Some item text for picture A
        \item<2-> Some item text for picture B
        \item<3-> Some item text for picture C
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]