# Change stuff after \pause

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want to achieve similar effect to this: [Updating picture after \pause](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156480/updating-picture-after-pause) 
but I want to change the previously displayed block.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}<1>{Example of Cloze style question}
    \underline{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }  is the man, who invented dynamite. \\
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<2>{Example of Cloze style question}
    \textbf{Nobel}  is the man, who invented dynamite.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to display the first box, with the underline gap and after pause, I want the second box to appear in the place of the first box. I know, I can just create multiple frames, but there is more stuff on the slide and I want to know, if there is a more elegant way to change something already displayed.

Comment: Welcome! Please help us to help you and provide a minimal working example with fully compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}`, ending with `\end{document}` and in between the code illustrating your problem. Its seldomly straight forward to guess, which packages people have used to obtain a certain output.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I will edit it in a minute!

Comment: `\only<1>{blabla}` and `\only<2>{blub}` might help

Comment: It actually did help, thanks :) I hope I will be able to solve all the problems with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the overlay as an argument of the block, the vertical alignment of the blocks will not be the same.

your example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}<1>{Example of Cloze style question}
    \underline{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }  is the man, who invented dynamite. \\
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<2>{Example of Cloze style question}
    \textbf{Nobel}  is the man, who invented dynamite.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With `\only` you can replace the text

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Example of Cloze style question}
            \only<+>{\underline{\phantom{Nobel}}} 
            \only<+->{\textbf{Nobel}}  
            is the man, who invented dynamite.
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Bonus:

With `\underline{\phantom{Nobel}}` you will get a line of the length of "Nobel".

Comment: Wow, your solution is so clean. Thank you very much!

Comment: May I also know, if there is an easy way to compile the LaTeX code in the question/answer and attach rendered pictures?

Comment: @Fulaphex Unfortunately not. There are tools which make it easy to copy code from the question, e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/copy-code/?src=api. My usual workflow is then to compile it on my computer, make a screenshot and copy the modified code into the answer and upload the screenshot.

Comment: Then I appreciate the effort even more. Thanks!